# How to use the Dictionary Items in Worksheet Function in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, dictionary, vba

I want to use the Dictionary Items in a worksheet function for as a range of values.

I use the below code to add items in dictionary and display the MAX (**WorksheetFunction.Max(Dic.Items())** of the items and it is working good.

But it is not working for the worksheet function RANK (**WorksheetFunction.Rank(7, Dic.Items(), 0))**

```
Sub DicTest()

Dim Dic As Scripting.Dictionary, i As Byte    
Set Dic = New Scripting.Dictionary

For i = 1 To 10    
    Dic.Add i, i    
Next i

MsgBox WorksheetFunction.Rank(7, Dic.Items(), 0)

End Sub
```

My goal is to get Rank of a value from Dictionary items.

Comment: `Rank` requires a range, it will not work with an array.

Answer (score 0):

You need some more understanding about how hash-tables (dictionaries) work. Try like this, using `F8` for debugging:

```
Option Explicit

Sub DicTest()

    Dim Dic As Object
    Dim i As Long

    Set Dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    For i = 1 To 10
        Dic.Add i * i, i ^ i * i
    Next i

    For i = 1 To 10
        Debug.Print Dic(i * i)
    Next i

End Sub
```

This is what you would get in the immediate window:

```
 1 
 8 
 81 
 1024 
 15625 
 279936 
 5764801 
 134217728 
 3486784401 
 100000000000
```

This is a good reference for dictionaries - https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-dictionary/